# Electron - importing exporting modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, module, electron, export

I'm working on a **electron-react-typescript** app.
I want to preload a database (sqlite) function call so that I can use that method in the renderer (react) environment.
For that, I prepare the function in another file called `testmgr.ts`

```ts
const dbmgr = require('./dbmgr'); //dbmgr is the file that prepares the database (its file on the pc)
const dbTest = dbmgr.db;

function getSomeNames() {
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM test';
    const stmt = dbTest.prepare(query);
    const res = stmt.all();
    return res;
}
export {};
```

Now in the `preload.ts` file, I have this:

```ts
const testMgr = require("./testmgr.ts");
const { contextBridge } = require("electron");

const getNames = () => {
  return testMgr.getSomeNames();
};
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", { getNames: getNames });`
```

when compiling, I get the following error in the console:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

If I remove `export {}` from the file `testmgr.ts`, I'll get this error

> testmgr.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.

What do I need to do, to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I hit the exact same issue. It was happening because I was writing some typescript to be executed with node, (i.e. `ts-node scripts/myscript.ts`), but there was already some typescript to be executed from the browser within the same repo. So there was already a `tsconfig.json` file in the root of the directory.

It looked like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

when I removed     `"module": "esnext",` then the command `ts-node scripts/myscript.ts` started to work.

Removing this line from the `tsconfig.json` file at the root of the repo wasn't the best solution because that would then break all the typescript code that has already been written for execution in the browser.

As my typescript code will be executed by node sits in a separate subfolder, I just copied the `tsconfig.json` file into that subfolder and removed the problematic line (    `"module": "esnext",`). That fixed it without affecting the code to be executed by the browser. Now running the command `ts-node scripts/myscript.ts` works fine. It must override the `tsconfig.json` at the root of the repo with the one that it finds within `scripts` folder.

UPDATE:
After a bit more experimentation, setting `target` to `es2017` and `module` to `node16` allows you to use more modern code (e.g. `async` and `await`):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "node16",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```